# Not resolved route fallback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns

Is there any way in angular routes to create a fallback route?
for example something like this:

```
    $routeProvider
    .when('/a', {
        templateUrl: 'a.html',
        controller: 'aCtrl'
    })

    .when('/b', {
        templateUrl: 'b.html', 
        controller: 'bCtrl',
        resolve: {/* some resolving */},
        fallbackRoute: 'a'
    })

    .when('/c', {
        templateUrl: 'c.html',
        controller: 'cCtrl'
    })

    .when('/d', {
        templateUrl: 'd.html', 
        controller: 'dCtrl',
        resolve: {/* some resolving */},
        fallbackRoute: 'c'
    })
```

From the example you can see that if the '/b' route is not resolved then it will be fallback to route '/a'.

is there any pattern to do so? `otherwise` won't work for me because a, c are different routes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation:
`If any of the promises are rejected the $routeChangeError event is fired.`

So you can subscribe to this event and redirect to any other route (using route details and properties). Please write if you need implementation example.